# Seaborn update scatterplot legend in loop

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a script to generate an sns scatterplot, followed by filtering the elements of the scatter plot, and then generating a new scatter plot. I have been able to filter mitigate one plot plotting over another with `plt.clf()`, but even with doing this, the legend does not update from the original plot. Ideally, the legend on the second plot would only include points that are actually present in the second plot. I tried addressing this by including `sns.reset_orig()` and `sns.reset_defaults` but these did not address the issue. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the first plot:
[image: Plot 1]

Here's the second (filtered) plot:
[image: Plot 2]

```
ax = sns.scatterplot('x', 'y', data=cell_localization_df, hue='t',linewidth=0, palette="deep")
ax.legend(loc='upper left',ncol=4, title="Cell #",bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize='small',title_fontsize='medium')

filtered_cells = pd.DataFrame()  
    for bb in cell_number_no_dups:
        cell_local_filter = cell_localization_df[cell_localization_df['cell_num'] == bb]
        if len(cell_local_filter) >=min_cell_pixels:
            if len(cell_local_filter) <=max_cell_pixels:
                filtered_cells = pd.concat([filtered_cells,cell_local_filter])
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
filtered_cells['g'] = filtered_cells['t'].astype('category') 
plt.clf()
sns.reset_defaults()
sns.reset_orig()
ax2 = sns.scatterplot('x', 'y', data=filtered_cells, hue='g',linewidth=0, palette="deep")
ax2.legend(loc='upper left',ncol=4, title="Cell #",bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize='small',title_fontsize='medium')
```

Comment: If `filtered_cells['t']` already was of type `'category'`, the assignment `filtered_cells['g'] = filtered_cells['t'].astype('category')` will keep the complete list of categories, whether they are present or not.  You could try `filtered_cells['g'] = filtered_cells['t'].astype(str)` to get rid of the unused categories.  Note that this will also change the colors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution to this after much digging. When plotting a scatter plot using pandas categories as the hue, the legend will not be accurate unless all categories are of the type `str`.